# How can add Code tag with Primefaces Rich text Editor?

Tags: primefaces, fckeditor

I am using primefaces RichTextEditor can it possible to use `<p></p>` with this text editor of primefaces something like  Stackoverflow using in this forum denoted by this {} symbol.

Comment: Any Idea about this issue @Baluc